# Can't upload gift wrapping image in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, gift-wrap

I am having trouble when I do step 8 and 9 of [Gift Wrap](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/sales/gift-wrap.html).
8. To upload a thumbnail Image of the gift wrapping, click Choose File. Then, select the file to upload from your directory. A thumbnail of the image appears in the Gift Wrapping Information after the record is saved.

9. Click Save.

When I 'Click Save' I get an error message showing up in a red rectangle near the top of the screen:
`'You have not uploaded the image.'`

I am using a .png file that has dimensions of 230x230 so it seems I am meeting all the requirements to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions on the folder to which magento saves uploaded images need to be set properly.  In some cases Magento tells you directly there is a permissions problem.  For example `cannot be created Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied`.  But for gift wrapping the error message is not as detailed.